# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client error popping up randomly

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have several asp.net pages running on a server which generally work without issue. However I've had the Server error "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client error" crop up twice seemingly randomly that affects all of my pages that interact with the DB server. A simple reboot of the webserver solves the issue and the pages run again with no problems. What could be causing this problem?